# Why the first copy constructor is called in the code below ?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Why the `B(B&)` ctor is called, instead of `B(const B&)`, in the construction of object `b1` ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B
{
    int i;
    B() : i(2) { }
    B(B& x) : i(x.i) { cout << "Copy constructor B(B&), i = " << i << endl; }
    B(const B& x) : i(x.i) { cout << "Copy constructor B(const B&), i = " << i << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    B b1(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13.3.3.2/3 says

> Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one
>   of the following rules apply:
>
> — Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence
>   S2 if :
>
> S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the references refer are the same
>   type except for top-level cv-qualifiers, and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is
>   more cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1 refers. [Example:

```
int f(const int &);
int f(int &);
...
int i;
int j = f(i); // calls f(int&)
```

In your case since the argument is non-const, the non-const version of the copy c-tor is chosen because it is a better match.

Comment: Great answer. Congratulations !

Answer (score 6):

This is because overload resolution applies, and since the argument to the constructor of `b1` is `b`, and `b` happens to be non-const lvalue, then the constructor taking non-const lvlalue is selected. And that's the first one. Interestingly, both are copy constructors, but your code would be equaly valid with just the latter one.

Comment: whole clause 12.8 in ISO/IEC 14882 is about copy constructors; anythying specific you are interested in?
As far as overloading goes ... that's whole chapter 13. And it's rather complex.

Comment: ... Plus a bunch of clauses relating to overload resolution... What is it that you are worried about?

Comment: @bronekk I can't find anything specifically related to my question in the Standard latest draft.

Comment: because there isn't; as I said there are whole clauses and chapters on the subject.

Answer (score 5):

Because b is not const. Therefore, it matches the first copy ctor perfectly, so that's what the compiler uses.

Comment: Could you give some reference ?

Answer (score 1):

because `b` is not a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main() {
    const B b;
    B b1(b);
}
```

Also, it's a hard decision wheter you should use *const* or not ;)